Register page error for keycloak jhipster login
I have jhipster 8 running with keycloak, and am able to log in correctly. However, when I enable user registration and and click 'register' on the login panel, I get an error page saying 'Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider.'
I also see the following in my docker console:  Failed authentication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction.buildPage(org.keycloak.authentication.FormContext, org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProvider)" because "action" is null.
I have tried creating a direct link straight to the register page with the following:
 <a href="http://localhost:9080/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/registrations?client_id=web_app&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080">
              <button>REGISTER</button>
            </a>

This led to a page saying internal server error.
I have also created a new realm within the environment provided by jhipster, and when I direct the above register button to this, I can reach a register page (although not hooked up to our database so I can't just use the new realm).
The setup worked previously and has recently stopped, so I wonder if there was a keycloak update that the jhipster realm setup cannot handle?

This should be fixed in JHipster 8.3.0. What version are you using?

I've recently created a new project with 8.3.0. The initial problems are resolved in that, but registering a new user is not saving to the jhi_user table.

Can you please enter an issue in JHipster's GitHub project and include steps to reproduce the problem.
